# From a bunch of n vectors, get all vectors which are mutually orthogonal

Tags: nlp, linear-algebra, countvectorizer

Original problem - context: NLP - from a list of *n* strings, choose all the strings which don't have common words (without considering the words in a pre-defined list of stop words)

Approach that I tried: using sklearn's count vectoriser, get the vectors for each string and compute dot product for each vector with every other vector. Those vectors with zero dot product will be added to a set.

This is done using O(n<sup>2</sup>) dot product computations. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is little you can do, suppose the trivial case where each string has a single unique word. In order to determine that all the intersections is empty you have to consider all the `n * (n - 1) / 2` pairs, hence complexity is `O(n^2*v)` and v is the number of unique words in your vocabulary.

For the typical case however we can have better approaches. Assuming that the number of words in each string is much less than the number of unique words it is better to iterate over the words of the maybe even skipping the vectorization. Let `0 < id[word] < nWords` be a unique number for each word

you could do

```py
v1 = np.zeros(nWords)
for i in range(len(strings)):
  for w in getWords(strings[i]):
      v1[id[w]] = 1;
  for j in range(i+1, len(strings)):
    for w in getWords(strings[j]):
      if v1[id[w]]:
        # strings[j] and strings[i] share at least one word.
        break
  for w in getWords(strings[i]):
      v1[id[w]] = 1;
```

still `O(n * C)`, where C is the number of words in all your strings.

You may want to precompute the `getWords(strings[i])`